# Reverse user input without for loop

Tags: python

How can i reverse input in python but if there is zero number remove it? now i using for loop

```
inpt = input()
rev_list = []
for i in inpt:
   if i != '0':
      rev_list.insert(0, i)

print(rev_list)
```

there is better way to handle it ?

Comment: you want to reverse the whole string and remove the '0' ? It's always a good idea to share somd input/expected output pairs ;)

Comment: So... 2002 would become 22? and 1002 would become 21?

Comment: Just giving an idea that you probably should provide sample input/output in an ideal scenario

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `inpt = input()[::-1].replace('0', '')`

Comment: where is zero number ?! `if there is zero number remove it`

Comment: right, I edited it